# writing a program to ban a user (by MAC address) from a network

Tags: language-agnostic, networking, wireshark

I'm not sure if this is possible at the application layer.  Can a program be written to read and analyze packets (maybe interfacing with wireshark through it's lua api) and ban MAC addresses with suspicious network traffic? (defining suspicious network traffic as packet injection patterns similar to known attacks)

Comment: I believe the router can be programmed to ignore certain IP addresses, but that is a question for ServerFault.

Comment: I'd like to do it at the application level, not modify router firmware

Comment: If it's your own application, it's easy enough to ignore packets you don't want. But I suspect you want to do something more sophisticated than that, like filter all traffic coming to your workstation. For that, you need a software firewall.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you mean by *"ban"* ?

Comment: Blacklist?  Disallow access to the network?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a combination [libnetfilter_queue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html) & iptables rules. libnetfilter_queue, through an Iptable rule, would give you all the packets (in userspace) which were queued by kernel packet filter. It would then wait for you to send a verdict for the packet.

Once you have netfilter_queue installed and have written a listening userland application, run an iptable rule like

```
iptable -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

A word of caution,this will give you all the packets and the kernel would then wait for you to give a verdict or if no user land application is running will just drop it.You can set iptables rule at various levels of granularity like src IP, protocol etc.

Once you have determined that the a particular MAC address has to be banned, run an iptables rule like (from your userland application you can use `system()` to run this iptable rule)

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:0F:EA:91:04:08 -j DROP
```

An example program on netfilter_queue is [here](http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/tjkopena/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=SWAT.NetfilterQueueNotes) to get you started. Hope it helps.

Another caution : Read up on iptables or ask at serverfault. There are multiple tables involved (input, output, mangle,prerouting,forward,nat etc) and I may be wrong to suggest mangle table for the iptable rule.